# Input Validation Template Reference ngFor

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to validate an input that is required in a *ngFor loop.
But I cant get a unique template Reference.
On Submit all Input fields are required / or none if at least one is filled out.

I tried to declare Template Reference like #optionContent_{{i}} but i can fill that in [ngClass].

Any help?

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && addOption()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let size of optionModel.optionContent let i = index">
   <div class="col-12">
     <label for="optionContent_{{i}}>Name Option</label>
        <input id="optionContent_{{i}}"
               type="text"
               #optionContent="ngModel"
               [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && optionContent.invalid }"
               required
               name="optionContent"
               [(ngModel)]="size.name"  class="form-control">
   </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in the name attribute they all have the same name, so ngForm gets confused try add dynamic name

```
<input ... name="optionContent{{i}}" ../>
```

Comment: I tried that already. But then how should I add it to the ngClass: [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && optionContent{{i}}.invalid }" does not work.

Comment: You are referencing in ngclass via template reference and leave the template reference as it is just change name attribute. Template reference is cycle scoped

Comment: That was it... Thx!